# Animation in React Native: Modify the height of a view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I managed to made a snack in Expo to simulate the Facebook Navigation bar hiding effect on scroll event, thanks to this amazing post:
https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-collapsible-navbar-e51a049b560a

Everything works like the Facebook main app.

Here you can find the snack: https://snack.expo.io/@univers3/barra-scomparsa

But now I need to put the scrollview inside a View and I was using this to modify the height of the ScrollView:

```
onScroll={Animated.event(
            [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollAnim } } }],
            { useNativeDriver: true },
          )}
```

The problem is this: if I will incapsulate the ScrollView into a normal View, this event (onScroll) is not available anymore for the parent View.
How I can achieve to modify the height of the parent View?

- Edit
  To let understand better my problem:
  I'm not able to reproduce the same behavior with this environment =>
  https://snack.expo.io/SkE2ORuH

Comment: Sorry i really not understand what you need yet.
Could you explain more or give some example image... etc.?

Comment: @Seyha i'm not able to recreate this behavior in this environment:
https://snack.expo.io/SkE2ORuHz

Comment: I see the Animated event call inline problem **onScroll={()=>Animated.event** you should remove and edit to **onScroll={Animated.event** and you will see the Title header will working fine as you expected. In the other hand, you should setting up the **TabView** header with the height dynamic in the **Scroll Event** too.
Please verify your code again then.

Comment: @Seyha solved the first problem, now the height of the TabViewAnimated is the though part, because if I modify only the height the "top" will be the same and I will have a hole. If I translate (Y) it, the height will remain the same and there will be a hole in the bottom.
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: As I see you have setup the height of the TabView that's make your height its fixed size. You can try on resize n reset the size by the scroll event via translateY, if m not wrong.